# C# - response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result> not working as I think it should work

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a winform app, and I am doing an API call to the GoogleMaps API. But for some reason I cannot get a response. Or actually, I do get a response but cannot do anything with it.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GoogleMaps
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            setup().Wait();
        }

        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task setup()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        }

        static async Task<Result> getAdress(int huisnummer, string postcode)
        {
            Result address = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"?address=00+1234AB&key=MYKEY");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                address = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
            }
            return address;
        }

        private async void BTN_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result address = new Result();

            address = await getAdress(31, "8256SC");

            richTextBox1.Text = "address is:" + address.formatted_address;
        }
    }
}
```

And my "Paste JSON as Classes" classes:

```
namespace GoogleMaps
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Result[] results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Address_Components[] address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address_Components
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

}
```

My output right now is just nothing. But I do get a 200 response. How do I fix this?

Comment: *My output right now is just nothing.* what you mean by that? is it empty instance? or what?

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to see the response data the Google server is returning. Does the server actually return that piece of information you are looking for?

Comment: My output is "address is: "

Comment: Maybe you're mapping to the wrong class. It seems like the structre has to begin with the RootObject. address = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();

Comment: Yes, it does return what I am looking for. Looked at it in the browser.

Comment: What are you doing with the two parameters `(int huisnummer, string postcode)` that you are passing to getAddress? Why aren't you using them? I tried the hardcoded location (`?address=00+1234AB`) that you are currently calling. It returns no results

Comment: No, don't use the browser. Use a tool (Fiddler) that shows the **Actual Real Data** transferred between the server and **Your Program**!

Comment: I used that address as a test. In a later stage it will obviously not be hardcoded anymore. @degant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are deserializing into the incorrect class. The correct class is `Rootobject`

```
address = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Rootobject>();
```

instead of using `Result`

```
address = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
```

Sample Geocoding API response ([from Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)):

```
{
    "results" : [
     {
         "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "1600",
            "short_name" : "1600",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         }]
    ...            
    }],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Yes, okay, I have tried that but how do I get the `formatted_address` now? 
I tried adding it to the rootobject but that did not work.

Comment: I am able to retrieve `formatted_address`. It is in the right place in your original classes posted in the question. There is no need to move it to RootObject.

Comment: But i am constantly getting errors if I just try whats looks good to me. When I only change `result` to `Rootobject` I get a convertion error. If I change them all to `Rootobject` it cant find `formatted_address`.

Comment: @LuukWuijster I had to make only one change in your code, which I've mentioned in the answer. After doing the change, all objects are loading perfectly fine for me (including `address.results[0].formatted_address`. The search string that I am using is: `?address=san%20fransisco`

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. So stupid I could't come up with that my self. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "");
        var response = client.GetAsync("products").Result;
        var root = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Root>>().Result;
        gridControl1.DataSource = root;
```

**//Root class with API data Atributes as model**

Comment: Some parts seem to be out of code boxes, please provide some context or sources for the code (avoid posting only code snippets)